# What are the rules/regulations for public transit passengers in St. Louis, Missouri?

Tags: usa, public-transport, regulations

What or where are the rules/regulations for [the transit services operated by Bi-State in St. Louis, Missouri, USA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-State_Development_Agency#Transit_services), especially [Metrolink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetroLink_%28St._Louis%29)? I'd like to know what rules I must follow as a passenger if I go there and ride the trains, and they don't appear to be online.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am the Online Media Specialist for STL Metro, and I can see your point that rules and regulations may not have a cohesive home on the website.

Are there specific questions I can answer for you? Basic riding rules including must have valid fare, no eating or drinking, no loud music, no pets except for service animals, no leaving your bags unattended.

Comment: Thanks. _All_ the rules would be nice, but the one I had in mind was.... I'm currently in StL and used MetroLink. When I got onto the platform, a guard asked to see my ticket. I questioned whether I really need to show it to her there, or if I need it only when on the train. She told me the former, so I showed her mine. Afterward I went online to see whether she was right, but couldn't find the rules anywhere.

Comment: Compare e.g. http://mta.info/nyct/rules/rules.htm.

Comment: Yes, the platform and the train are part of the fare zone (passengers must have a ticket to be on the platform or train, very similar to other transit agencies). I'm sorry the website wasn't clearer about that, and will work to fix that.

Comment: I'll accept (checkmark) this answer as the most complete I'm going to get, since an employee has stated the rules aren't online. I do hope they get there at some point. Thanks for your information, @CourtneyS.

Comment: Thanks for the MTA comparison. I can see the usefulness of having such clear guidelines available, especially for out-of-town riders. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Having ridden on Metrolink a couple times when there, I'm not sure there ARE any. :(

But here's where the offical answer is buried on their site: http://www.metrostlouis.org/metrolink/

See in particular the "How to Ride":

> Remember, using radios without ear plugs, smoking (including electronic cigarettes), eating and drinking are prohibited on all Metro transit vehicles. Please be courteous to other passengers by obeying these rules.

Comment: You get +1 and my thanks, but no checkmark. Those links are to nice displays of the rules, but I'm sure the rules themselves (assuming they exist, which I do) must be much drier and in legalese.

Comment: Compare e.g. http://mta.info/nyct/rules/rules.htm